# Unable to access netcore service when registered as windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services

I try to run a simple web api sample using netcore as windows service. However, if I run this as console app it is fine and I can access it through the browser. But after installing the netcore app as service it is not accessible through the browser. Any ideas what I miss here?

This is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // following works if I use Run() and execute on commandline
        // instead of calling RunAsService()
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

As you see… nothing special here. In fact, this is the code generated by Visual Studio when using the asp.netcore skeleton.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

With the generated controller this should return some values as text printout under api/values. So I just call https://localhost:5001/api/values.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Somehow this works as console but not as service.

I use the command

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained
```

so there is a WebApplication1.exe (according to the test project name) created in the publish folder (together with dependencies).

Then I register this exe as service

```
sc create "TestService" binPath= "C:\Projects\Playground\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win10-x64\publish\WebApplication1.exe"
```

and then call

```
sc start "TestService"
```

It seems to work. However, I get no response when trying to access the service through the url.

What is missing here?

Comment: `https://localhost:5001` is, most likely, the Visual Studio URL. Try to run `dotnet WebApplication1.exe` or `dotnet WebApplication1.dll`, you'll see the port used is not the same (commonly something in the range of 44300 and 44399)

Comment: How to set the port then?

Comment: [`UseUrls(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#server-urls)

Comment: The UseUrls does work. Also, In the Windows Services, I had to right click my service and change the 'Log On' to my domain\username and password, else it would die.

Answer (score 0):

As my test, it seems there is something missing in [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

First, I suggest you check whether you could access `http://localhost:5000/api/values`.

For `https`, it will need to access dev certificate which is normally installed under current user store. If you did not change the Service Account after create the service, it will run under `Local System Account` which will fail to access the certificate.

For a solution, you could try running the service under your `User Account`.

For another way, you could try to configure the certificate like below:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                // Configure the app here.
            })
            .UseKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
                    {
                        var cert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                            "localhost", "My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                            allowInvalid: true);
                        httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
                        {
                            return cert;
                        };
                    });
                });
            })
            .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to create service in Aspnet core. **IHostedService** interface is used to create services like **Windows Service**.

Use **IHostedService** in the WebApi project and deploy it as a Web project. As soon as the API project will start your service gets started.

**Service Code:**
Create a Class **MyHostedService.cs** and put the below code into this class.

**Class**

```
public class MyHostedService:IHostedService 
{
  private Timer _timer { get; set; }
}
```

**Start**

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(OrderExportPurgeTimeInterval));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Stop**

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _timer ?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Your DoWork**

```
private void DoWork(object state)
{
    bool hasLock = false;
    try
      {
        Monitor.TryEnter(_locker, ref hasLock);
        if (hasLock)
        {
            PurgeProcessor.ProcessPurge().Wait();
        }
      }
      finally
      {
          if (hasLock) Monitor.Exit(_locker);
      }
 }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I exhibit this issue when my service runs under the local system account.  If I add the administrator under the service as the log-in account everything works.

Seems like a permissions issue to me.